# I wanted to modify the response for array of object

Tags: node.js, arrays, express, node.js-connect

I wanted to modify the response for array of object.
I have below result.
And i wanted to change the response to specific response.

```
let result = [
  {
    team_id: 1,
    team_name: 'Avengers',
    participant1: 98,
    participant2: 99,
    participant3: 100,
    participant4: 101,
    phase1: 0,
    phase2: 0,
    phase3: 0,
    phase4: 0,
    phase5: 0,
    participant1_name: 'test 1003',
    participant2_name: 'test 1002',
    participant3_name: 'test 1004',
    participant4_name: 'test 1005'
  }
]
```

And wanted to convert to below.

```
[
{
    "team_id": 1,
    "team_name": "Avengers",
    "phase1": 0,
    "phase2": 0,
    "phase3": 0,
    "phase4": 0,
    "phase5": 0,
    "participantDetails": [
        {
            "participant1": 98,
            "participant1_name": "test 1003"
        },
        {
            "participant2": 99,
            "participant2_name": "test 1002"
        },
        {
            "participant3": 100,
            "participant3_name": "test 1004"
        },
        {
            "participant4": 101,
            "participant4_name": "test 1005"
        }
    ]
}
```

]

I have tried below: -

```
const data = result.map((elem) => {
                    const participantDetails = [];
                    for (let keys in elem) {
                      if (keys.startsWith('participant')) {
                        console.log('elem:-',elem);
                        participantDetails.push({
                          [keys]: elem[keys]
                        })
                        delete elem[keys]
                      }
                    }
                    return {
                      ...elem,
                      participantDetails: participantDetails
                    }
                  });
```

I have filter participant but not sure how to filter names also.
And they are having different positions for that.

Please help thanks in advance.

Comment: Added my attempts @jeeves

Comment: Will it always be in the format of participant# and participant#_name?

Comment: yes @FaitAccompli

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're already in the right direction. You don't have to filter for participant names since you can easily derive them once you filtered the participant.

Here's my approach:

```js
let result = [
    {
        team_id: 1,
        team_name: 'Avengers',
        participant1: 98,
        participant2: 99,
        participant3: 100,
        participant4: 101,
        phase1: 0,
        phase2: 0,
        phase3: 0,
        phase4: 0,
        phase5: 0,
        participant1_name: 'test 1003',
        participant2_name: 'test 1002',
        participant3_name: 'test 1004',
        participant4_name: 'test 1005',
    },
];
for (let obj of result) {
    let participantDetails = [];
    Object.keys(obj)
        .filter((key) => /^participant\d+$/.test(key))
        .forEach((key) => {
            participantDetails.push({
                [key]: obj[key],
                [`${key}_name`]: obj[`${key}_name`],
            });
            delete obj[key];
            delete obj[`${key}_name`];
        });
    obj.participantDetails = participantDetails;
}

console.log(JSON.stringify(result, null, 4));
```

Notice that I used regex to filter strictly on `participant`. From there, I can derive the values for `participant_names` and push them into the `participantDetails` array.

It is also important to note that you are modifying the values of the `result` array. If you want to keep those values, you can use `map` instead to create a new instance of the array.